# Inspecting HTTPS connections in Tornado (Python) to identify slowness

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ssl, tornado

I'm using a 3rd party API pretty heavily in my Tornado app, and it seems like after eliminating some other inefficiencies, I'm still experiencing 300-600ms response times per request. My best guess is that Tornado is re-negotiating the SSL connection every time, but I'm not sure how to get insight into where the request slowness is coming from.

I'm looking for something that will break down each phase of the connection by time, like "Certificate received: 100ms" and "Server response: 200ms"

I'm typically doing multiple asynchronous requests to the same server, like this:

```
liked_response, following_response, subscribed_response = \
yield [gen.Task(http_client.fetch, like_request),
       gen.Task(http_client.fetch, following_request),
       gen.Task(http_client.fetch, subscribed_request)]
```

How can I look deeper into Tornado's networking stack, to identify which parts of my request are being slow?

Comment: Time to break out netcat and wireshark

Comment: And a debugger while your there

Comment: @JakobBowyer Thanks, that actually helped a lot to get some visibility on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best chances for debugging something like this would be `netcat` and `wireshark`or if you can find something that you can pipe your web process into to do some monitoring. Something similar to `django-debug-toolbar`

Comment: Thanks, I used Wireshark to inspect the handshake and found that that's about 50% of the latency I'm experiencing. The other 50% is transmitting the data.